# ODAC 10.20221 visual studio integration

Tags: visual-studio, odac

I've downloaded ODAC1020221.exe from oracle website.  It installed 10g client but neither VS2008 nor VS2010 sees ODAC provider.  Oracle client 11 doesn't work with our oracle server (9.1 version), but just for the sake of test I've tried to install it and visual studio sees ODP.NET fine.
ODP.NET 10 supports only 1 and 2 framework?  VS2008 and 2010 do not see ODP.NET 10 because of that?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 should see the provider. If you try to add a reference can you see Oracle.DataAccess available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odac is only compatible with 10g and up